# Form theming with templates

Tags: 7, theming, forms

Please could someone explain why the following doesn't work?

This is in the form build:

```
$form['#theme'] = 'some_form';
```

Here's the hook_theme function:

```
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
      'some_form' => array(
        'template' => 'some-form',
        'variables' => array('form' => NULL),
      ),
    );
}
```

The template (some-form.tpl.php):

```
<div id="some-form">
<?php print render($form); ?>
</div>
```

You can see the wrapper markup from the template file but the form is not being output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're attaching the `#theme` to an element, you need to user `render element` in your theme declaration in place of `variables`:

```
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'some_form' => array(
      'template' => 'some-form',
      'render element' => 'form'
    ),
  );
}
```

After you clear the caches your template should start being used for that form.

See [`hook_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) for more information.

Just another thought, if your template file is as trivial as just wrapping the form in a tag you can use the `#prefix` and `#suffix` properties on the `$form` object instead of using a theme at all:

```
$form['#prefix'] = '<div id="some-form">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks Clive, doesnt appear to work though, just get a popup prompting me to download some random file??????

Comment: Would of done the other suggestion but the wrapper markup is going to be a bit more extensive than in this example.

Comment: Ah it might be because you had `tpl.php` at the end of the `template` property in `hook_theme()`...the theme engine adds that automatically so you don't need to. I've updated the answer. Remember to clear the caches after every change you make in `hook_theme()`

Comment: No sorry, not sure why I put that in that in the question but no tpl.php. Have corrected this now.

Comment: Hmmm can't think why, that's definitely the right way to do it. Try comparing your code to the examples on [Theming forms in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/1067612) and see if you can find the discrepancy

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to insert at the beginning of your TEMPLATE file.

```
<?php
  echo render( $form['form_id']);
  echo render( $form['form_build_id']);
  echo render( $form['form_token']);
  echo render( $form['options']['status']);
?>
```